# Existe alguma forma de testar uma animação CSS pelo DevTools?

Tags: css3, navegador-de-internet, css-animations, keyframes, dev-tools

Tenho essa animação simples feita em CSS, porém estou tendo dificuldades para "*debuggar*" seu comportamento. Toda hora tenho que ir no código, salvar, e atualizar no browser.

Existe alguma forma de testar uma animação direto pelo DevTools?

Tipo tem como parar a animação em determinado segundo e avaliar como ela está, ou ver como o elemento vai estar em determinado segundo?

```css
.box {
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 width: 400px;
 height: 200px;
 margin-left: -200px;
 overflow: hidden;
 background: #333;
}

.bola {
 position: absolute;
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 top: 75px;
 left: 175px;
 background: #999;
 border-radius: 50%;
 -webkit-animation: bolax 2s ease-in-out infinite;
 animation: bolax 2s ease-in-out infinite;
}
.bola:nth-child(2) {
 animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bolax {
 0%, 100% {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-150px);
 }
 50% {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(150px);
 }
}
@keyframes bolax {
 0%, 100% {
  transform: translateX(-150px);
 }
 50% {
  transform: translateX(150px);
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
 <div class="bola"></div>
 <div class="bola"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O Firefox possui o [*animation inspector*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Work_with_animations), nele você pode "debugar" animações, bem como avançar/regredir o estado da mesma para visualizar como seria o seu comportamento na tela. Basta abrir as ferramentas de desenvolvedor (<kbd>F12</kbd>) e procurar pela aba "Animations".

<kbd>[image: Animation Inspector]</kbd>

Comment: Parece que é por ai mesmo. Vc sabe se pelo DevTools do FF tem como editar o `timing function` para mudar o tipo de `ease` também? Ou só tem esse *timeline* como recurso?