# Como configurar os css das keyframes para o Firefox?

Tags: css, wordpress, animação

Boa Tarde

Minha dúvida é referente a configuração das keysframes para o navegador Mozilla Firefox

No navegador Chrome utilizei a seguinte configuração :

```css
 #unidade-movel {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 97px;
   -webkit-animation: unidade-movel 10s infinite ;
  animation: unidade-movel 10s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes  unidade-movel {
0% {
    top: 20px;
    left: 0%;
}

10% {
    top: 20px;
    left: 10%;
}
20% {
    top: 20px;
    left: 20%;
}
30% {
    top: 20px;
    left: 30%;
}
40% {
    top: 20px;
    left: 40%;
}
45% {
    top: 130px;
    left: 45%;
}
50% {
    top: 150px;
    left: 40%;
}
60% {
    top: 150px;
    left: 25%;
}
70% {
    top: 180px;
    left: 20%;
}
80% {
    top: 205px;
    left: 20%;
}
90% {
    top: 280px;
    left: 20%;
}
100% {
    top: 280px;
    left: 100%;
}
}
```

Para o mozilla firefox utilizei a seguinte configuração:

```css
@keyframes unidade-movel {
0% {
    top: 20px;
    left: 0%;
}

10% {
    top: 20px;
    left: 10%;
}
20% {
    top: 20px;
    left: 20%;
}
30% {
    top: 20px;
    left: 30%;
}
40% {
    top: 20px;
    left: 40%;
}
45% {
    top: 130px;
    left: 45%;
}
50% {
    top: 150px;
    left: 40%;
}
60% {
    top: 150px;
    left: 25%;
}
70% {
    top: 180px;
    left: 20%;
}
80% {
    top: 205px;
    left: 20%;
}
90% {
    top: 280px;
    left: 20%;
}
100% {
    top: 280px;
    left: 100%;
}
}
```

O problema encontrado é o seguinte, no mozilla firefox a animação fica no topo do site quando o correto é ficar no meio e quando faço a inspecção do elemento não consigo reposicionar o elemento utilizando o css, creio que a configuração para o mozilla não esteja correta, em algumas pesquisas que fiz fui orientado a colocar um -moz-keyframe ou -moz-animation fiz no código mas também não surtiu efeito em outras pesquisas fui orientado a retirar o -moz- mas sem sucesso!
Gostaria de uma orientação, desde já agradeço!

Comment: Recomendo a leitura: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3674

Comment: Diretamente relacionado ao `animation` e ao `keyframe`, não era para ter diferenças. A partir da versão **16** do Firefox e **43** do Chrome, tanto o `animation` quanto o `keyframe` foram totalmente compatibilizados. Não há necessidade* do prefixo do browser. Provavelmente o seu problema está relacionado a outros elementos do seu código. Sendo assim, seria melhor você [edit] a sua pergunta e postar mais alguns códigos que estão diretamente relacionados a esse problema. [Comp. keyframe](https://caniuse.com/#search=keyframe) e [Comp. animation](https://caniuse.com/#search=animation).

Comment: Cara testei sua animação tanto no Chrome quanto no FF e nos dois browser ele renderiza a animação no topo da página... Para inspecionar a animação e debugar vc pode ver alguns detalhes nessa pergunta, as vezes te ajuda https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/347470/existe-alguma-forma-de-testar-uma-anima%C3%A7%C3%A3o-css-pelo-devtools mas se possível coloca o código completo ai, sem ele não da para te ajudar muito mais